# Class inheritance and instances interaction

Tags: php, oop, class, variables, scope

I have 2 classes that inherits from a `father` class. The "father" class has a `protected` variable that is being populated in both of the `child` classes, each of the classes populates it with different information for a database.

My problem is that when I create instances of both classes, the second instance changes the the values from the first instance.

Here is the code:

```
class User
{
    //array with the MySQL Server details//
    private $serverInfoArray = array("host" => HOST, "user" => USER, "pass" => PASS);

    protected $data; //This will be populated with data in both of the "child" classes.

    //some database connection functions....//

    public function setData(){} //implemented on "child" classess

    public function getData(){} //implemented on "child" classess

}
```

and here are one the `child` classes:

```
class Producer extends User
{

    function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->setData($id);  
    }

    public function setData($id)
    {
        global $serverInfoArray, $data;
        $connectionFB;

        $query = "MY FIRST QUERY"; //IN THE SECOND CHILD CLASS 
                                   //IT HAS DIFFERENT QUERY

        $result = mysql_query($query, $connectionFB);

        $i=0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $data[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }     
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        global $data;
        return $data;    
    } 
}
```

The second class has the same structure but is different in its name and the query being executed. Its declaration is `class Account extends User`

When I create 2 instances:

```
$producer = new Producer($_SESSION['PRODUCER_ID']); 
$account = new Account($_SESSION['ACCOUNT_ID']);
```

and do this:

```
  var_dump($producer->getData());
```

I get the values of `$data` that was populated by the second query. If I wont create the `account` instance it will return the values of populated in the first class.

Why does the `account` instance changes the values of `$data` from the `producer` class instance, how can I separate them ?

Thanks.

Comment: You start your question about protected class variable, but the actual methods don't use them. Not helpful ;) - And why don't you do the actual mysql query in the parent/base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the following line:

   ```
   global $serverInfoArray, $data;
   ```
2. Use `$this->serverInfoArray` & `$this->data` to access class variables.

Comment: Thanks, I sure know the use of `$this`, but because I had a typing mistake for accessing the class variables (`$this->$data` instead of `$this->data`) I got problems and started to get loose with the global definitions... Now it is all good, and I got my mind arranged again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

$data is not a global var, so why do you use `global` ?

You should use `$this->data` and `$this->serverInfoArray`

Comment: I've tried to use it but then it does't fill the array with results

Comment: you should use also $this->serverInfoArray

Comment: @Alon_A you should use $this always when you refer to class variables